# VueJs + BootstrapVue: Table delete items only on first page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I created a page where I list all my items in a BootstrapVue b-table. for each item, I added the possibility to delete the item.

When I activate pagination with b-pagination element and :per-page attribute, I have an unexpected behavior on the page. The problem is it works only for the 1st page, but all others pages get the data of the 1st page. For example, if the total item is 10 and I'm displaying 5 items per page, the second page displaying the next 5 items will still try to delete the first page items.

```
<b-table
  id="traffic-routes"
  :fields="fieldsForTrafficRoutes"
  :items="itemsForTrafficRoutes"
  :per-page="perPageForTrafficRoutes"
  :current-page="currentPageForTrafficRoutes"
>
    <template v-slot:cell(action)="data">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <a class="action-icon mr-2"
          @click="removeRow(data.index)"
        > Delete </a>
     </div>
   </template>  

</b-table>

<b-pagination
  v-model="currentPageForTrafficRoutes"
  aria-controls="traffic-routes"
  align="right"
  :total-rows="
  itemsForTrafficRoutes ? itemsForTrafficRoutes.length : 0"
  :per-page="perPageForTrafficRoutes"
></b-pagination>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      perPageForTrafficRoutes: 5,
      currentPageForTrafficRoutes: 1,
      // ...
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getAllTrafficRoutes',
    ]),
    itemsForTrafficRoutes() {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getAllTrafficRoutes));
    },
  }
}
```

However, I tried to make the items dynamic:

```
itemsForTrafficRoutes() {
  const foo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getAllTrafficRoutes));
  return foo.slice((this.currentPageForTrafficRoutes - 1) *
    this.perPageForTrafficRoutes, this.currentPageForTrafficRoutes * this.perPageForTrafficRoutes
  );
},
```

This will make the items unique for each page, it will only contain the first 5 on the first and then update to the next 5 items on the next page, however, the table only displays the first page and is empty on the next page even though the items are present

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're using the `index` from the scoped slot.
The index will be based the *displayed* rows, and not the actual index of the item in the array provided to the `items` prop.

This is described on the docs down in the notes under the [Scoped field slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots) section.

> `index` will not always be the actual row's index number, as it is computed after filtering, sorting and pagination have been applied to the original table data. The `index` value will refer to the **displayed row number**. This number will align with the indexes from the optional v-model bound variable.

I would suggest either using a unique identifier from your object if you have one, or using the reference to remove it.